# ExecutorService InvokeAny is running all callables to completion

Tags: java, executorservice

I have two functions that each compute the same thing in a different way. I do not care which object I use, but just need to take whichever finishes first. To accomplish this, I am trying to use an ExecutorService using the invokeAny() method, like shown below. However, when I run my code, both method1 and method2 are run all the way to completion, even when method1 has a sleep for 10 minutes inserted to ensure it does not finish before method 2. I know that both complete because of log statements that are emitted just before the return inside both methods. Is there something I am missing about how this should work?

```
final ImmutableList.Builder<Callable<MyObject>> callableBuilder = ImmutableList.builder();
        callableBuilder.add( () -> this.method1( arg1, arg2 ) );

        callableBuilder.add( () -> this.method2( arg1, arg2 ) );

        try
        {

            final MyObject myObject = this.executorService.invokeAny( callableBuilder.build() );
            return myObject;
        }
        catch ( final InterruptedException e )
        {
            throw new CustomException( "Interrupted exception", e );
        }
        catch ( final ExecutionException e )
        {
            throw new CustomException( "Execution exception", e );
        }
```

Each method looks something like

```
method1( arg1, arg2) {
try {
// Lots of logic and external service calls
 log("method1"):
}
catch ( CustomException e)
{
throw e;
}
```

Comment: How many threads was your `executorService` given?

Comment: You bring up log statements and methods being executed but don't show any of it. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: The executor service was given 2 threads, one for each method. I can't post inside the methods themselves for security reasons, but the basis of each method has been edited in the original example